# How can I set UI interface of Eclipse in undock mode as in Netbeans?

Tags: eclipse

There is an option in Netbeans that allows for a section of their UI interface to have its own window, allowing me to drag it to another monitor (see [this link](https://ui.netbeans.org/docs/ui/floating_windows/floating_windows.html#behavior) and appended picture).

[image]

I have search in Eclipse for this same behavior but unfortunatly I haven't found it.

Is this feature available in eclipse (natively or by plugin)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in eclipse natively. just drag the view outside you'll get the same behavior. I use eclipse 4.6. I remember seeing this from 4.4.